# Datagridview is not refreshing after inserting data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I know this question has been asked more than an acceptable amount of times, but believe me I've tried every solution on each question already show, and it isn't working. After doing the button update function and populating the database, the data grid view is supposed to refresh but it doesnt. I've tried .refesh() and .invalidate() and .update() but those dont work either.

Edit: Even if I add a manual refresh button, pressing on that won't show the newest database information. Only by going to another form then returning to this form does the new data show.

This is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Construction
{
    public partial class Payments : Form
    {
        //Connection String of the Application
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ToString());
        public Payments()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadData();
        }

        private void loadData()
        {

            //check if connection is closed, if so open it
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPaymentLimit.Text.ToString()))
                    return;
                int limit = Int32.Parse(tbPaymentLimit.Text.ToString());
                string query = "SELECT TOP " + limit + " * FROM MiscPayments WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '" + dtPickerFrom.Value + "' AND '" + dtPickerTo.Value + "';";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dgvPayments.DataSource = dt;
                dgvPayments.ResetBindings();
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oops! An error has occured. Please restart the application");
            }

            //close the connection if it is still open
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create the login page
            Login toPage = new Login();
            //show the login page
            toPage.Show();
            //hide the current page
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnHomepage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //create the homepage
            Homepage toPage = new Homepage();
            //show the homepage
            toPage.Show();
            //hide the current page
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void tbPaymentLimit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

        private void tbPaymentLimit_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

        private void dtPickerFrom_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

        private void dtPickerTo_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

        private void btnPaymentUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPPaid.Text.ToString()) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPDesc.Text.ToString()))
            { return; }

            //check if connection is closed, if so open it
            if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            try
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO MiscPayments (Description, Paid, DateTime) VALUES (@Description, @Paid, @DateTime)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbPDesc.Text.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", Double.Parse(tbPPaid.Text.ToString()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                loadData();



                MessageBox.Show("Payment of " + tbPPaid.Text.ToString() + " has been successfully added");
                tbPPaid.Text = "";
                tbPDesc.Text = "";
            }

            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oops! An error has occured. Please recheck what you entered");
            }

            //close the connection if it is still open
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Use parameters in your sql to avoid injection.  Put your disposable sql connections in a using-block to avoid your connections staying open.

Comment: `.Refesh()`, `.Invalidate()` and `.Update()` (the former is a combination of the other two) are related to the graphic interface, not the data. If you replace the object used as DataSource of your DGV, then set the `.DataSource` to `null` beforehand

Comment: I already tried that it didn't work. The problem is weird because I have another page with pretty much the same code that's updating instantly while this one isn't.

Comment: I also made it so that the entire form is destroyed and remade after insertion, it updates but it remains 1 update behind each time. So like If I update with 1 it wont show immediately, but if I update with 2 1 will show and 2 will show when I do the next update. Very weird indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be with the datetime. If I changed the query to "Select * form MiscPayments", the table will update normally.

I solved this by creating a new load function with the same code except for this:  `string query = "SELECT TOP " + limit + " * FROM MiscPayments WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '" + dtPickerFrom.Value + "' AND '" + DateTime.Now + "';";`

Answer (score 0):

```
     try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbPaymentLimit.Text.ToString()))
                    return;
                int limit = Int32.Parse(tbPaymentLimit.Text.ToString());
                string query = "SELECT TOP " + limit + " * FROM MiscPayments WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '" + dtPickerFrom.Value + "' AND '" + dtPickerTo.Value + "';";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dgvPayments.DataSource = dt;
                dgvPayments.Refresh(); //Just Refresh the DataGrid it will work 
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Oops! An error has occured. Please restart the application");
            }
```